# Linksys router pleasw help me

Tags: xbox360

Ok so my dad locked my xbox's internet through our router, i usually have no problem with it becaue i was so busy, but ive gotten my acceptance letter to my college and now i have nothing to do if you could tell me how t hack into it that would be great.

he has already changed it fro the default

Answer (score 2):

Please do not ask for "hacking" issues/solutions.  We are here to help with ethical solutions.  If you are looking to get your XBox back on the network, it sounds like you will have to sit down and have a talk with your dad.

Comment: hahaha trust ive more than tried that, if i even bring it up he gets mad. my family is indian so you you any other indian families you will know how strict there parents are

Comment: Perhaps he considers you might spend the time between now and your enrollment in a more constructive manner. It isn't the place of SuperUser to undermine your parents' authority to control your access to the internet they pay for.

Comment: @Kruug: this is not an answer. It should be a comment.

Comment: @Xavierjazz I just received the ability to make a comment everywhere.  That is why I chose to type it as an answer as opposed to a comment.